# Suggest the usage of example.com for examples when URLs are encountered

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

Could the editor suggest the using of **example.com** for URL examples when it encounters URLs in a question that's being typed?

Not only would this help remedy inadvertent linking to legitimate websites like http://abc.com,  http://domain.com, http://mysite.com, etc., it would also educate the users about the existence of http://example.com.

I know that this could be potentially annoying if it leads to a lot of false positives, but it could be really worth a shot.

Comment: Though I propose `http://localhost/` not bring up the annoyance. :)

Comment: @sarnold - example.com is reserved in RFC 2606 explicitly for this purpose

Comment: @awoodland: I know. I've even talked with the guys who ran the domain when I was curious about it ages ago. I just think that there's plenty of times when people put `http://localhost:3000/blahblah/blort` in a question, and we shouldn't suggest replacing them with `example.com`. I think it'd distract from the often-amazingly-useful fact that they're doing something on `localhost`.

Comment: @sarnold - I misread your comment the first time around then

Comment: Ironically your post inadvertently links to said sites. :P

Answer (score 2):

I just checked the 20 most-recently posted questions on SO. Of the 20, 19 had no links. The one link is in [Key as a variable for backbone.js model.set()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117345/key-as-a-variable-for-backbone-js-model-set) and is a link to the `model.set()` documentation.

So, it (a) doesn't seem to be a huge problem; (b) the only link I quickly found, should definitely not be example.com.

I hit refresh and check another 14 new questions. This time, 2 links. [How to change character set in Oracle 11g r2 Express edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117416/how-to-change-character-set-in-oracle-11g-r2-express-edition) links to Oracle documentation (again, not a candidate for example.com). [How do I apply dependency injection to an abstract factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117403/how-do-i-apply-dependency-injection-to-an-abstract-factory) links to another question on StackOverflow.

Figuring, OK, maybe problematic links are tag-specific, I tried [html](/questions/tagged/html). Of the most-recent ten questions (including checking previous revisions on these), none had links (though [PHP/MYSQL - checking user identification from DB info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116145/php-mysql-checking-user-identification-from-db-info) thought it wise to post his MySQL username and password).

Trying again, [css](/questions/tagged/css): There were four links in three questions (out of 10). [Drop down navigation in fluid design, getting overflow when page resized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116817/drop-down-navigation-in-fluid-design-getting-overflow-when-page-resized) linked to jsFiddle. [GWT-suggestbox style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116326/gwt-suggestbox-style) linked to Google Web Toolkit docs. [Linking Wufoo to an external stylesheet without SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116193/linking-wufoo-to-an-external-stylesheet-without-ssl) linked to support forums and documentation.

So, in summary, 7 out of 7 links I found should not be example.com. An example.com suggestion would have a *very* high false-positive rate.